# Which is a Better Solution in this scenario of WCF

Tags: wcf, windows-services

i have a WCF service which Monitors a Particular Drive and Creates a New Folder weekly which i am using as a Document Storage

i have many Drives configured for Document Storage  and i have to Monitor which Drive is Active(only one drive can be Active at one time ) and on Weekly Basis i have to Add a new Folder in My Active Drive at a predefined Path 
provided at the configuration Time.
The Client can make any Drive Inactive or the drive can become Inactive if it is Full and i need to make another Drive Active dynamically using a Service based on priority for example 
i have following drives 
drive A  priority 1 Active yes
drive B priority 2 Active no

if A Becomes Full i have to Make Drive B as Active

> Now should i Implement a WCF Service in IIS or as a Windows Service as My Program Will Watch has to Perform Many Actions Like check the drive size and make another drive Active and send Updates in the Database

Which is a Better Way IIS or Windows Service

> I need A Service which Get the Information about Drives path From the Database and I have a Configuration WIndows Application which needs to communicate with this Service also to check the drive path and Check the size if it is invalid Application will not Configure the Drive Path and if it is valid it will keep the entry in the Database and any client can have multiple directories and only one directory will be Active So that i can Store Documents in it
>
> What about the Performance and can i configure WCF for IIS like IIS does not Refresh the Application Pool as i want my Service to Run periodically say every 30minutes – Nitin Bourai just now edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me a better architecture would be to have a service responsible for persisting your Documents, it can then decide where (and how) to store it and where to read it from based on who's requesting it / how much disk space is available etc. This way all your persistance implementation details are hidden from consumers - they only need to care about Documents, not how they are persisted.

As to how to host it... there is lots of useful information out there documenting both:

IIS : [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx)
Windows Service: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733069.aspx)

Both would be more than capable of hosting such a service.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with a windows service in this case.  Unless I misunderstand, you want this all to happen with no human intervention, correct?  So, I don't see a contract, which means its not a good candidate for WCF.

Comment: I need A Service which Get the Information about Drives path From the Database and I have a Configuration WIndows Application which needs to communicate with this Service also to check the drive path and Check the size if it is invalid Application will not Configure the Drive Path and if it is valid it will keep the entry in the Database and any client can have multiple directories and only one directory will be Active So that i can Store Documents in it

Answer (score 0):

As I see it both Windows Service or IIS hosted service will work well in your scenario. Having said that, I would go with the Windows Service. It is just a feeling matter but I guess you have a little more config support 'out of the box'. I believes it is easier to config what to do if it fail to start, config the user you want the service to run with and so on.
But as I said, it is a matter of feeling

Comment: Just a Matter of Feeling ,What about the Performance and can i configure WCF for IIS like IIS does not Refresh the Application Pool as i want my Service to Run periodically say every 30minutes

Comment: if you want to run your service every 30 minutes it should be part of the logic of your service. You should not depend on the platform for that... I'm not saying it won't work I just don't like it :)

Comment: I Just want a Solution Which can be extensible ,i know both will work but i like to know which one is better in terms of performance and Extensibility

Comment: there's no sure one only solution for that... for a real good answer to your question you'll have to prototype both scenarios and measure... it takes longer but that probably the best approach on finding the right answer